# Suggest a Data Structure that support the following operations with time complexity O(log(n))

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, binary-search-trees, avl-trees

I’m looking for a data structure that supports that store the salaries of it’s employees.

- Insert(e) – Insert employee e into the data structure.
- AvgDecile(k) – Returns the average salary of the k’th decile.
- MedianDecile(k) – Returns the median of the k’th decile of the
  salaries. The ten deciles of a data set divide it into ten equal
  parts. That is, in a data set of size n, the k’th decile is defined
  to be all values with rank between (k − 1)n/10 and kn/10. So, for
  example, if k = 2, the function needs to return the median among all
  salaries whose rank is between n/10 and 2n/10.
  Hint: what is the rank of the element you are looking for?

my assignment is on the following data-structures:

AVL tree - it does support the basic methods with this complexity, but in order to find which elements are larger, I need to search through all tree which can cost more than ()

A combination of the two above - looked promising at first, but again, I couldn't find a way to find those elements.

BST - binary search tree.

Comment: AVL is a version of a balanced binary seqrch tree

Comment: Have you been introduced to *augmented* search trees, to *order statistic* data structures?

Comment: Yes I did them @greybeard

Comment: `Yes I did [both augmented search trees and order statistic data structures` Well, which of *average* and *median* is already covered with a balanced order statistic tree, and *how*? What do you need to add to support the other one?